# Trouble with Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get Selenium working, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've installed the proper Ruby gem, and am trying to execute this code.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
element.submit

puts driver.title

driver.quit
```

I'm fairly certain my issue is that I haven't connected the ChromeDriver correctly. How do I link Chrome driver in order to get this to work? It says I need to place it on my PATH. Can someone explain this?

[Here is what I downloaded.](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Also, here is the error I'm getting:

```
in `executable_path': Unable to find the chromedriver executable.
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path=` method that allows specifying of the chromedriver executable:

```
# Specify the driver path
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = "path/to/chromedriver.exe"

# now instantiate chrome driver 
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
element.submit

puts driver.title

driver.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Place chrome driver depends on your operating system, check [this link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver):

> ```
> OS    Expected Location of Chrome
> Linux /usr/bin/google-chrome1
> Mac   /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
> Windows XP    %HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> Windows Vista C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find the chromedriver executable :
We get this when system is not able to locate chromedriver. We can help system find it by setting environment variable "webdriver.chrome.driver"
If you are running unix/linux use 
`export webdriver.chrome.driver=<path_where_binary_is_present>`
If running on windows :
Go to System Advanced Environment Variables. Add an entry with name webdriver.chrome.driver and value set to path of binary

We can also set this location from program also. Like in java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ""

Do any one of this and this error should go away